# Need to figure out an average of cells based on 22 days prior to today

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, sum

I have an all-encompassing spreadsheet in Google that I need to total up based on a date. I need to figure out the daily usage of items going out based on the date. So.. I have a column (A) with dates. Each cell =today(). I have a column with outgoing items (I). I need to average items in column I based on the last 22 days. Any help?

I also need to figure out weekly and monthly totals, but that can be another topic.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Capture of forumla]

```
=AVERAGEIF($A:$A,">"&TODAY()-22,I:I)
```